# MSMQ HTTP server communication with non-.NET clients

Tags: http, msmq, sap, endpoint

Is MSMQ compatible with non .NET platforms? I have an MSMQ service hosted by IIS for HTTP support, and would like to see if an SAP system is able to access it.  Is it possible for an SAP system to use/call a MSMQ HTTP service?

I have attempted to use SoapUI to test the MSMQ HTTP service as well, but I keep getting an error with a status of "Bad Request" in the HTTP response.  I have no problems with C# clients who send messages to the queue with the endpoint "FormatName:DIRECT=http:////msmq/Private$/".  With SoapUI, I had to remove the FormatName:DIRECT from the endpoint otherwise SoapUI wouldnt understand or do anything with it.

My MSMQ service is a C# .NET 4.0 system, using the System.Messaging library to create and read from the queue.

Answer (score 0):

"Is MSMQ compatible with non .NET platforms?"
Yes. MSMQ pre-dates .NET but I don't think that's what you are asking.

"Is it possible for an SAP system to use/call a MSMQ HTTP service?"
HTTP is just the protocol to allow you to transport messages from your local queue manager to a remote queue manager (on the other side of a web site). 
The SAP system would therefore have to be MSMQ-aware and be designed to interact with its local MSMQ queue manager.
Although it's possible to send a POST that contains the correct MSMQ structure expected by the MSMQ listener running in IIS, you also need to handle the flow of ackowledgements that come back from the website.

Cheers
John Breakwell